# Как уменьшить файл логов транзакций SQL базы?

Tags: sql-server

Дана база SQL с файлом логов транзакции.
Каждую ночь автоматически через *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016*  делаются полные бэкапы.
Модель восстановления - полная. Автосжатие отключено.

Теперь о проблеме.
Размер базы - 4 Гб, логов - 49 Гб, что неприемлимо.
**Хочу освободить физическое место на диске.**
При выборе сжатия файла журнала он указывает на 17 Мб. (0%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При использовании полной модели восстановления или модели
>   восстановления с неполным протоколированием, необходимо регулярно
>   создавать резервную копию журнала транзакций, для снижения вероятности потери результатов работы и для усечения
>   журнала транзакций.

Подробнее по ссылкам: [Создание резервной копии журнала транзакций](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server),
[Резервные копии журналов транзакций](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/transaction-log-backups-sql-server)

Также существует возможность усечения файла лога:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
GO  
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (AdventureWorks2012_Log, 1);  
GO  
-- Reset the database recovery model.  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO
```

Подробнее по ссылке: [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql).

Comment: Тогда уж следует и сказать, чем может быть чревато такое переключение моделей  восстановления для усечения лога (автора вопроса, судя по всему, это не коснется, поскольку бэкап логов, похоже, у него не делается, но, мало ли, кто-то другой решит последовать совету...).

Answer (score 3):

Полная модель восстановления подразумевает регулярные бэкапы журнала транзакций. После каждого бэкапа журнал транзакций сокращается.

Если вы не собираетесь делать регулярные бэкапы - модель восстановления нужно сменить на простую.